# add_edge(v1, v2, graph)- time complexity

Tags: c++, boost

I need to build a graph and trying to decide how (for minimum time complexity).

From my understanding, there are two popular ways to store the graph's data: [adjacency_list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) and [adjacency_matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html).

The declaration of the graph is (undirected for example):

```
typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> UGraph; // In case of adjacency_list

typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS> UGraph; // In case of adjacency_matrix
```

Both cases are using the function `add_edge(v1,v2,UGraph)` to add an edge between two vertices.

So my question is which model will make `add_edge` be less expensive — in time complexity manner and why?

I tried to read [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) explanation about time complexity of `add_edge` but this explanation is about `OutEdgeList`. So it got me confused.

Which model is less expensive for `add_edge` and why?

Comment: why are you linking to the documentation for version 1.38 of boost? That's from 2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my question is which data base will make add_edge be less expensive- in time complexity manner and why?

It's faster ( O(1) ) in matrix in comparison to adjacency list in which you need to traverse the whole list attached to particular vertex to add an edge.

Comment: and with the matrix you 'rais' the cell [i][j] to '1' in O(1)?